How can I remove this part of vs code?

I want to remove this part of vscode as it hinders with the code I want to see. any ideas how to remove it?
I've tried to remove the file navigation bar but it didn't work. any other way or extension i should use?

Right click on the section then uncheck sticky scroll


You can go to vs settings and write enable sticky scroll and disable it
